# How does AACplus v2 perform in comparison to AAC?

Tags: audio, encoding, aac

Which of these audio codecs provides better quality? I want to encode my audio files to lower lower bitrate and maximum quality.

Answer (score 4):

[HE-AAC v2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Efficiency_Advanced_Audio_Coding) (the standardized name of what is "aacPlus v2" as a trade name) supersedes the [AAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) standard.

It has been extensively tested, and results suggest that it provides excellent quality even at 48 kBit/s (whereas MP3 only scored as "poor"). I can only recommend to look into this [2009 EBU Technical Review](http://tech.ebu.ch/docs/techreview/trev_305-moser.pdf) for a detailed description.

Here, you can see the subjective scores (higher is better) for various bitrates.

[image]

Another figure that shows how it results in better quality at lower bitrates:

[image]

To summarize:

> Preliminary studies show that the compression efficiency of AAC can be
>   increased by a factor of up to four.
>   HE-AAC v2 – the combination of AAC, SBR and PS – is undoubtedly the most powerful audio codec
>   available today.  It is thus the first choice for all application scenarios where bandwidth is limited or
>   very expensive, such as digital broadcasting or mobile applications

It should be noted though that if you want to use bitrates above 128 kBit/s, there is no point whatsoever in using HE-AAC, since you won't hear a difference.